# Been to America three times/for three times

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

> I have been to America three times.

Vs

> I have been to America **for** three times.

Is *for* necessary here?
Or is the use of preposition futile here?

Comment: By the way, we don't put spaces before question marks in English.

Comment: Subrat, what @snailboat just told you is something that has been [mentioned before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/169585/revisions). As people edit your questions, please learn from those edits. By the time you've asked your 50th question, you should not be making the same formatting mistakes over and over again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can go to America for three days, three weeks, three months, but you can't go for three times.

> I have been to America three times.
>   Last time, I stayed for three weeks.

Answer (score 6):

In your example

> **for**

is not used. "***for***" is used to express duration of time, not number of times.

> I have been in America **for** two years.
>
> **For** the past three times I've been to America, it has rained.
>   *During the past three times I've been to America, it has rained.*

Comment: I don't like either of your last two sentences; I think they read better with no preposition at all: _The past three times I've been to America, it has rained._

Comment: You would also use "for" to express the purpose: "I went to America for a job", or "I went to get a job". But "for to get a job" is incorrect; you may hear or see it as a vernacular or for humour, but it's not correct.

Comment: Neither of those sentences are grammatical to me either.

Comment: @J.R. surely with 'for' it means that it rained for the entire trip (which seems unlikely, but is how I would understand the sentence), whereas your correction just states that it rained at least once

Comment: Au101 - If I wanted to say it rained the whole time, I wouldn't do so by appending a "for" to the start of that sentence.

Comment: @J.R. Well no neither would I to be honest with you, but I think your correction means/implies/suggests something different, even if it's very likely that your correction means what the original sentence was intended to mean, I don't think it quite means what the original sentence does mean. If you know what I mean :P

Comment: @CCTO "for to" plus infinitive was also common in earlier times, as in "and all countries came into Egypt to Joseph for to buy corn."